# Extending SDK public interfaces without breaking older SDK compiled apps and new Runtime

Tags: c#, interface, sdk

Our product has sdk and runtime part. SDK loads runtime dll dynamically so that we can ship runtime improvements without having older apps recompiled.

I have an interface in sdk library, mysdk.dll, `MyInterface1`. The actual implementation is `MyClass1` in myruntime.dll.

Now, i want to add a new method `foo` in `MyInterface1` and use in runtime code of myruntime.dll. However, older apps are breaking as older `MyInterface1` do not have `foo`. What is the right way to extend `MyInterface1` without breaking older apps ?

I thought about adding another interface `MyInterface2` inherited from `MyInterace1` and using `obj is MyInterface2` or looking at `version` field in `MyInterface1`. However, this again fails at runtime as `MyInterface2` is not present in older SDK.

What is the right way to extend interface of publicly released SDK so that older apps still work ?

I believe that this problem is common across all languages.

Comment: You need to pick a language and stick with it please. Is this C# or C++? Also, why would your second option be a problem? If an app is built to target a newer interface, it should fail if someone gives it an older SDK.

Comment: @DavidG I have moved the problem to C#. For second question, answer is in first line of question. Thanks

Comment: No updates till now. :(